# Ease animation in slidingdrawer

Tags: android, android-animation, interpolation, slidingdrawer

I want to slowdown SlidingDrawer opening speed using interpolator (DecelerateInterpolator)
Is this possible. i want to implement ease animation.

```
final Animation slowDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(((Swipe)getActivity()), R.anim.ease);
```

this is XML

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Using this i am not getting what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if You want only open/close that sliding layout, than I would suggest to use custom `ViewGroup` instead of deprecated `SlidingDrawer`. Below is some simple example of that implementation:

```
public class MySimpleSlidingDrawer extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int SLIDING_TIME = 500;

    private View mHandle;
    private int mHandleId;
    private View mContent;
    private int mContentId;

    private ObjectAnimator mOpenAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "slide", 0f, 1f);
    private ObjectAnimator mCloseAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "slide", 1f, 0f);

    private int mAnimationTime = SLIDING_TIME;
    private boolean mOpened = false;

    private int mSlideHeight = 0;

    public MySimpleSlidingDrawer(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public MySimpleSlidingDrawer(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MySimpleSlidingDrawer(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MySlidingDrawer, defStyle, 0);

        mHandleId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MySlidingDrawer_handle, 0);
        mContentId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MySlidingDrawer_content, 0);

        mOpenAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        mOpenAnimator.setDuration(SLIDING_TIME);
        mCloseAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        mCloseAnimator.setDuration(SLIDING_TIME);

        setClipChildren(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        if (getChildCount() != 2) {
            throw new InflateException("Only to child are supported for this layout");
        }

        if (mHandleId != 0) {
            mHandle = findViewById(mHandleId);
        } else {
            mHandle = getChildAt(0);
        }

        if (mContentId != 0) {
            mContent = findViewById(mContentId);
        } else {
            mContent = getChildAt(1);
        }

        final LayoutParams handleParams = (LayoutParams) mHandle.getLayoutParams();

        handleParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        handleParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        handleParams.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1/* true */);
        handleParams.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 1/* true */);
        mHandle.setLayoutParams(handleParams);

        mHandle.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        if (mSlideHeight == 0) {
            mSlideHeight = getHeight() - mHandle.getHeight();
        }

        // Handle have been clicked. Execute animation depending on open / close state
        if (!mOpened) {
            mOpened = true;

            mCloseAnimator.cancel();
            mOpenAnimator.start();
        } else {
            mOpened = false;

            mOpenAnimator.cancel();
            mCloseAnimator.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets slide percent value
     *
     * @param slidePercent % of slide (0 - closed, 1 - opened)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public void setSlide(final float slidePercent) {
        final LayoutParams handleParams = (LayoutParams) mHandle.getLayoutParams();

        handleParams.bottomMargin = (int) (slidePercent * mSlideHeight);
        mHandle.setLayoutParams(handleParams);

        final LayoutParams contentParams = (LayoutParams) mContent.getLayoutParams();

        contentParams.bottomMargin = (int) -((1- slidePercent) * mSlideHeight);
        mContent.setLayoutParams(contentParams);
    }

    /**
     * Sets open interpolator
     *
     * @param interpolator {@link android.view.animation.Interpolator} for open animation
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public void setOpenInterpolator(final Interpolator interpolator) {
        if (mOpenAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mOpenAnimator.cancel();
        }

        mOpenAnimator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    }

    /**
     * Sets close interpolator
     *
     * @param interpolator {@link android.view.animation.Interpolator} for close animation
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public void setCloseInterpolator(final Interpolator interpolator) {
        if (mCloseAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mCloseAnimator.cancel();
        }

        mCloseAnimator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Trick to avoid content to be resized - measure it as it visible
        final int contentHeightMeasure = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredHeight() - mHandle.getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        final int contentWidthMeasure = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        mContent.measure(contentHeightMeasure, contentWidthMeasure);

        if (mSlideHeight == 0) {
            mSlideHeight = getMeasuredHeight() - mHandle.getMeasuredHeight();

            final LayoutParams contentParams = (LayoutParams) mContent.getLayoutParams();

            contentParams.height = mSlideHeight;
            contentParams.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1 /* true */);
            contentParams.bottomMargin = - mSlideHeight;

            mContent.setLayoutParams(contentParams);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: it's not optimized or tested a lot, but basic functionality works.

Another way is to adapt existing `SlidingDrawer` code to your need. For me it looks not so easy or flexible, because of its existing implementation specific. First of all, it clear mentioned in [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) documentation:

> This class is not supported anymore. It is recommended you base your
>   own implementation on the source code for the Android Open Source
>   Project if you must use it in your application.

And there's no animation change API exposed by `SlidingDrawer`. The main problem is that there's no *animation* at all, some timing event is just sent to update view position, here:

```
private void doAnimation() {
    if (mAnimating) {
        incrementAnimation();
        if (mAnimationPosition >= mBottomOffset + (mVertical ? getHeight() : getWidth()) - 1) {
            mAnimating = false;
            closeDrawer();
        } else if (mAnimationPosition < mTopOffset) {
            mAnimating = false;
            openDrawer();
        } else {
            moveHandle((int) mAnimationPosition);
            mCurrentAnimationTime += ANIMATION_FRAME_DURATION;
            mHandler.sendMessageAtTime(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_ANIMATE),
                    mCurrentAnimationTime);
        }
    }
}
```

So, in order to modify interpolation, you will need to change what animation logic or provide your own. Second way is safer, because doesn't affect existing logic. Below is some draft variant how to do it (to detect exact changes comparing with original `SlidingDrawer` open below class diff with original API 19 version from your android SDK installation), only changed code is presented below:

```
public class MySlidingDrawer extends ViewGroup {

    /** Click animation duration */
    // TODO: ideally you should properly calculate that value
    private static final long CLICK_ANIMATION_DURATION = 1000;

    /** New field for custom interpolator */
    private TimeInterpolator mAnimationInterpolator = new BounceInterpolator();
    /** just to distinguish click and moving by user animations */
    private boolean mAnimatedClick = false;
    /** Specific click animator */
    private ObjectAnimator mClickToggleAnimation;
    /** Specific listener just to handle animation end properly */
    private Animator.AnimatorListener mClickAnimationListener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(final Animator animation) {
            // nothing to do here
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animation) {
            mAnimating = false;
            // Determine if it close or open, by comparing to some final value
            if (mAnimationPosition == mTopOffset) {
                openDrawer();
            } else {
                closeDrawer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(final Animator animation) {
            // TODO: should be handled properly
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animator animation) {

        }
    };

    ...

    /**
     * Creates a new SlidingDrawer from a specified set of attributes defined in XML.
     *
     * @param context The application's environment.
     * @param attrs The attributes defined in XML.
     */
    public MySlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mLocked) {
            return true;
        }

        if (mTracking) {
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    moveHandle((int) (mVertical ? event.getY() : event.getX()) - mTouchDelta);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
                    velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(mVelocityUnits);

                    float yVelocity = velocityTracker.getYVelocity();
                    float xVelocity = velocityTracker.getXVelocity();
                    boolean negative;

                    final boolean vertical = mVertical;
                    if (vertical) {
                        negative = yVelocity < 0;
                        if (xVelocity < 0) {
                            xVelocity = -xVelocity;
                        }
                        if (xVelocity > mMaximumMinorVelocity) {
                            xVelocity = mMaximumMinorVelocity;
                        }
                    } else {
                        negative = xVelocity < 0;
                        if (yVelocity < 0) {
                            yVelocity = -yVelocity;
                        }
                        if (yVelocity > mMaximumMinorVelocity) {
                            yVelocity = mMaximumMinorVelocity;
                        }
                    }

                    float velocity = (float) Math.hypot(xVelocity, yVelocity);
                    if (negative) {
                        velocity = -velocity;
                    }

                    final int top = mHandle.getTop();
                    final int left = mHandle.getLeft();

                    if (Math.abs(velocity) < mMaximumTapVelocity) {
                        if (vertical ? (mExpanded && top < mTapThreshold + mTopOffset) ||
                                (!mExpanded && top > mBottomOffset + getBottom() - getTop() -
                                        mHandleHeight - mTapThreshold) :
                                (mExpanded && left < mTapThreshold + mTopOffset) ||
                                        (!mExpanded && left > mBottomOffset + getRight() - getLeft() -
                                                mHandleWidth - mTapThreshold)) {

                            if (mAllowSingleTap) {
                                playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

                                animateToggle();
                                /*
                                if (mExpanded) {
                                    animateClose(vertical ? top : left);
                                } else {
                                    animateOpen(vertical ? top : left);
                                }
                                */
                            } else {
                                performFling(vertical ? top : left, velocity, false);
                            }

                        } else {
                            performFling(vertical ? top : left, velocity, false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        performFling(vertical ? top : left, velocity, false);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return mTracking || mAnimating || super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Toggles the drawer open and close with an animation.
     *
     * @see #open()
     * @see #close()
     * @see #animateClose()
     * @see #animateOpen()
     * @see #toggle()
     */
    public void animateToggle() {
        mAnimatedClick = true;
        if (!mExpanded) {
            animateClickOpen();
        } else {
            animateClickClose();
        }
    }

    /**
     * For doing our animation for close
     */
    private void animateClickClose() {
        mAnimating = true;
        mClickToggleAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "togglePosition", (int) mAnimationPosition, mBottomOffset + (mVertical ? getHeight() : getWidth()) - 1);
        mClickToggleAnimation.setInterpolator(mAnimationInterpolator);
        mClickToggleAnimation.setDuration(CLICK_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        mClickToggleAnimation.addListener(mClickAnimationListener);
        mClickToggleAnimation.start();
    }

    /**
     * For doing our animation for open
     */
    private void animateClickOpen() {
        mAnimating = true;
        mClickToggleAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "togglePosition", (int)mAnimationPosition, mTopOffset);
        mClickToggleAnimation.setInterpolator(mAnimationInterpolator);
        mClickToggleAnimation.setDuration(CLICK_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        mClickToggleAnimation.addListener(mClickAnimationListener);
        mClickToggleAnimation.start();
    }

    /**
     * Sets current animation position
     *
     * @param position to be set
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public void setTogglePosition(final int position) {
        mAnimationPosition = position;
        moveHandle((int) mAnimationPosition);
    }

    ...

    private class DrawerToggler implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mLocked) {
                return;
            }
            // mAllowSingleTap isn't relevant here; you're *always*
            // allowed to open/close the drawer by clicking with the
            // trackball.

            if (mAnimateOnClick) {
                animateToggle();
            } else {
                toggle();
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    /**
     * New API to modify timing of interpolator
     *
     * @param interpolator {@link android.animation.TimeInterpolator} to be used for onClick open / close
     *
     * TODO: it's also possible to add XML attribute for the same
     */
    public void setAnimationInterpolator(final TimeInterpolator interpolator) {
        mAnimationInterpolator = interpolator;
    }
}
```

And there's xml I've used for testing (only one sliding drawer section should be enabled):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.alexstarc.testapp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Some fragment with main content of activity screen -->
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.alexstarc.testapp.VoteListFragment"
        android:tag="mainFragment"/>

    <com.alexstarc.testapp.MySlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        custom:handle="@+id/handle"
        custom:orientation="vertical"
        custom:content="@+id/content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/cover"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    </com.alexstarc.testapp.MySlidingDrawer>
    <!--
    <com.alexstarc.testapp.MySimpleSlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        custom:handle="@+id/handle"
        custom:content="@+id/content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/cover"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    </com.alexstarc.testapp.MySimpleSlidingDrawer>
    -->
</RelativeLayout>
```